# Displaying contents in a table view as cells in a section

Tags: objective-c

I have two arrays. One with student details and other with staff details. These details in array is obtained by changing the segments in a view controller. And i want to display these arrays in two sections as cell contents. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple working implementation of what I think you're looking for:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // here is the staff and students array for demonstration purposes
    self.staff = @[@"Mr. Jones", @"Mrs. Smith", @"Principal Alfred", @"Miss Agnes"];
    self.students = @[@"Timmy", @"Joey", @"Suzie"];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // there will be two sections, the staff array in the first section
    // and the student array for the second section
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // if this section is the first section, return the number of cells as there
    // are staff entries in the array, otherwise this is the second section so we
    // can return the number of students in the array
    return section == 0 ? self.staff.count : self.students.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // try to reuse a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    // if we had no cells to reuse, create one
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    // now we can customize the cell based on the index path. If this is the first section
    // we want to display the staff information, and if this is the second section we want to display
    // the student information, but in both cases we use the row to figure out which entry in each
    // array we want to use. Assuming the arrays are filled with name strings, we can just set the
    // textLabel's text to the name for this section/row
    NSString *name = indexPath.section == 0 ? self.staff[indexPath.row] : self.students[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = name;

    // then return the cell
    return cell;
}

@end
```

[image]

Just in case you aren't familiar with in-line conditionals, the two are exactly the same:

```
// this means return the count of the staff array if the section is 0, otherwise return the
// count of the student array, just like the if-statement below
return section == 0 ? self.staff.count : self.students.count;

// this is the same as the in-line conditional above, and while less concise and compact,
// it is more likely understood in many cases
if (section == 0) {
    return self.staff.count;
}
else {
    return self.students.count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mike. This is what i'm looking for. I think this is the best answer. But i'm not allocating the array with details. I'm just getting the array contents as user inputs from the other view controller.

Comment: So do you understand what to do or do you need help?

Comment: Yeah. I know what to do further. Thanks for your help. If I click on an image, how to store that in an array. And if I select another image, I want to replace the older image. Could you help me with this?

Comment: If you only want to use/store one image, why us an array? I would just use an instance variable.

Comment: I have to select an image from some images displayed and some text have to be get from the textfield.

Comment: Suppose those images are pictures of various students and staffs. I want to give a name in the text-field and pick a picture from the images listed.